# no route between my location an destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i'm using MapWithRoutes code from here [MapWithRoutes][1]

[1]: https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes . it gives me correct location and destination but cannot calculate routes between them i think the 
     problem in this  code:

```
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: 
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, 
f.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, 
t.longitude];

NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?
output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"
([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
 }
```

or may be in viewing the route:

```
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: 
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, 
f.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, 
t.longitude];

NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?
output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"
([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
}
```

whats wrong with codes return no routes?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: whats wrong with code that no route is shown on map?

Comment: Very bad code example. How are setting your polyline in your map ? Is your function returning a polyline ?

Comment: yes it has decodePolyLine ,check the full code in git hub link.

Answer (score 2):

Draw Polyline based on route in Mkmapview 
check this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457879/5593725)